# Why my homepage doesn't display a cms block content?

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-block

I have programmatically created a CMS block, which is working fine. I've added some content into it and trying to display it in my homepage.

My block identifier is `this_is_a_block_identifier`. I'm trying to call it in `content->pages->home page->edit` by adding:

```
{{block class=Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="this_is_a_block_identifier"}}
```

After, I'm clearing a cache. But instead of displaying a content, it just displays a text, which is that block class calling (as I showed above).

Why?

Answer (score 4):

To call static block in cms page

```
 {{block  id="this_is_a_block_identifier"}}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-call-static-block/#)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have forget to use " before **Magento\Cms** so please use below code .

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="this_is_a_block_identifier"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question, it seems that you have typo mistake in calling the block.

```
{{block class=Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="this_is_a_block_identifier"}}
```

should be

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="this_is_a_block_identifier"}}
```

Notice the double quote before **`Magento`**.

Comment: I did that, but this doesn't help. I got just a text in my home page.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that your forgot to enable the block for the store view of your home page. There's a list widget just above the block content of the block edit page. You can use Ctrl + click to select multiple store view where the block should show up.